# Downloading file from https page using python urllib2

Tags: python, sharepoint, urllib2

I am trying to download a excel file from sharepoint server using python 2.6.8 urllib2 library.
As Sharepoint is password protected I am also passing Username and password.

My code looks like this.

```
import urllib2
import os.path

theurl = 'https://Mycompany.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=XXXX&file=IPS_cleaned.xlsx&action=defaultclear'
username = ''
password = ''
headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

req = urllib2.Request(theurl, None, headers)
pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
with open('/home/neilshah/newfile.xlsx',"wb") as code:
    code.write(pagehandle.read())
```

It gives me following error.

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import urllib2,base64

request = urllib2.Request(theurl)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: try using requests library

Comment: Now Error is     
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=url)
(Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)..

Comment: Maybe is something with the microsoft server